# Throw an error including the connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, error-handling

I have a c# .NET web application using EF to connect to SQL Server databases, and it is throwing an 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0' error. This only happens on my remote server, it works fine locally. Clearly my connection string is incorrect, and my question is not directly about this error.

My application has 5 contexts matching 5 SQL Server databases, and each has a connection string in my web.config file. I know that the first context is working, but I don't know which of the other contexts is the problem. The 5 connection strings in web.config are all pretty similar and I can't see why any are not working if the first one (that is clearly working) is working. All 5 connection strings used to work, what has changed.

So I want some more clues.

Here is my stack trace from my YSOD:

```
[ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +1739
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +191
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +136
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +76
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +35
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +241
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +78
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +116
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +931
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext) +509
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +77
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection() +16
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver) +508
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase) +370
   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +140
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +483
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +177
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +274
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +77
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues) +32
   Argus.RdAP.GetCodeFromIndex(Int32 IndexNumber) +140
(etc...)
```

OK, here's my question: it would be really handy if I could see what the bad connection string was. I have a pretty good idea of where in the code the problem is starting (i.e. in Argus.RdAP.GetCodeFromIndex). Is there a try ... catch ... throw piece of code that will include the actual connection string in the exception that is thrown?

Sorry if this is a stupid question. Also - alternate suggestions for accessing the connection string or fixing my underlying issue are welcome.

Comment: I basically would prevent writing the contents of the connection string to an exception (i.e. log file/server/...) Connection strings might include confidential information like passwords.

Comment: My connection string has no passwords, and this is a very temporary measure, but great point, thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found the answer!

```
try
{
    // here was the method I suspected of causing the problem
}
catch
{
    throw new Exception(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString);
}
```